# Why is my Javascript restarting every time I press enter in the Input area? codepen attached

Tags: javascript, jquery, codepen

I'm working on an exercise on codepen.io and I don't know why, every time that I press the enter key in the input area, the program restarts itself, although I've added some ifs statements to avoid it.

I've tried the same code here in stackoverflow and the Javascript It doesn't restart itself, I attach the link to codepen for you to see the problem in action:

http://codepen.io/rafahuelin/pen/qRdWBy?editors=0010

I suppose that the reason is something I'm not aware of. Could you please, tell me what's causing this to happen and what's the way to manage this program behavior?

Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Appears the magnifier icon
  var initializeSearch = false;
  if (initializeSearch === false) {
    initializeSearch = true;
    $("#search").html("<div id='magnifier' class='search-init animated fadeIn'> <div id='magnifier-stick' class='stick-appears'></div> </div>");
    console.log("after #search");


    // When clicking on the icon appears the input form
    var magnifierClicked = false;
    $("#search").on("click", function() {
      if (magnifierClicked === false) {
        magnifierClicked = true;
        $("#magnifier-stick").addClass("animated fadeOut stick-disappears").removeClass("stick-appears");
        console.log("after magnifier-stick");
        $(".search-init").addClass("search-input").removeClass("search-init");
        console.log("after search-init");
        setTimeout(function() { //waits for 1.2s
          $("#search").html("<div id='search-input'><form><input id='input-form' class='animated fadeIn' type='text' name='searchContent' placeholder='Type Your Search Here...'></form></div>");
          console.log("after search-input");
          $("#input-form").focus();
        }, 1200);
      } // if(magnifierClicked === false) 
    });
  } // avoid for looping if (initializeSearch === false)
  //After pressing Enter, 
  // $("#input-form").keypress("pressedKey", function(pressedKey){
  //  if(pressedKey === 13){
  //   //Disable textbox to prevent multiple submit
  //     $("#input-form").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  //   console.log("key pressed");
  //  }
  // });

  //send request to API


  //search-input moves up 
  // function moveItUp() {
  //  $("#input-form").addClass("test");   //.addClass("animated fadeOut stick-disappears").removeClass("stick-appears");
  // } 


  //and the results appear down


}); // $(document).ready
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.search-init {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  border: 4px solid green;
  border-radius: 35px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -ms-animation-duration: 3s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
}
#magnifier-stick.stick-appears {
  height: 20px;
  width: 0;
  border: 2px solid green;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 54px;
  left: 54px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.search-input,
#search-input {
  height: 70px;
  width: 570px;
  border: 4px solid green;
  border-radius: 35px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 400ms 400ms ease;
}
#magnifier-stick.stick-disappears {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 2px solid green;
  transform: rotate(-95deg);
  top: 54px;
  left: 54px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 200ms ease;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.2s;
  -ms-animation-duration: 0.2s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.2s;
}
.search-input,
#search-input {
  line-height: 56px;
}
#input-form,
#input-form:focus {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 35px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search">
</div>
```

Comment: Because you have a form, and pressing enter submits the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New answer based on the discussion in comments:**

The OP asked:

> i don't know why, every time that I press the enter key in the input
>   area, the program restarts itself, although I've added some ifs
>   statements to avoid it.

So I assumed that he is asking about disabling the form submission when pressing enter key. Since OP found this behavior different in Stackoverflow than Codepen. He wanted to imitate the same concept on Codepen.

OP commented out this code because it was not working:

```
 //After pressing Enter, 
  // $("#input-form").keypress("pressedKey", function(pressedKey){
  //    if(pressedKey === 13){
  //        //Disable textbox to prevent multiple submit
  //     $("#input-form").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  //        console.log("key pressed");
  //    }
  // });
```

The reason is that is not working is because OP used keypress instead of keyup (or keydown). keypress event handles printable characters (which does not include Enter key). Therefore I suggested the below answer.

**Old answer:**

You can handle form submission like so:

```
$("#search").on("submit", function() {
    // You can return false to stop it or handle anyway you like
    return false;
});
```

A codepen snippet: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RKPQaO

Comment: This is not an answer. Read the question correctly.

Comment: It is an answer to half of the question.

Comment: No, not even close. The question is, why is it not submitting in Stack Overflow Snippets.

Comment: "and what's the way to manage this program behavior?" on codepen

Comment: Oh okay, fine... I'll remove my downvote. Thanks for telling.

Comment: And the question was about why submitting on Codepen not why it is not submitting on Stackoverflow.

Comment: That's exactly what I answered for. Why it is not submitting on Stack Overflow. Because of the sandbox.

Comment: Providing the codepen snippet doesn't matter. Coz **it works in Codepen** already.

Comment: The OP asked "every time that I press the enter key in the input area, the program restarts itself, although I've added some ifs statements to avoid it.". He tried to avoid the restart on Codepen not Stackoverflow. Your answer gives him a direction toward that but does not entirely answer his question.

Comment: In codepen, if you see, he has commented out them. The return false or event.preventDefault is commented out.

Comment: I saw that. However, the question itself says something else. In any case, lets let the OP decide. I really don't understand the downvotes.

Comment: Line's 29 to 43 are commented. Yes. I downvoted for one reason, but since you were nice enough to explain me, I removed them. But it should be the same reason bro.

Comment: Thanks for removing the downvote. I think i explained my answer to the best of ability. Hopefully, whoever also downvotes will read the comments and reassess his decision.

Comment: I would find they wouldn't because, OP is already doing it. So this renders your suggestion useless. My few cents. `:)`

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys. I've learned from both of your answers. Kalimah, your answer was spot on. You put me on the right path :)

Comment: Glad that you accepted my answer. I would appreciate if you also upvoted as well.

Comment: @Rafa Wow, I didn't know that you didn't wanna know the reason behind it, and I thought you are already using what Kalimah has provided. Deceiving question. LoL.

Comment: @KalimahApps Your answer is spot on, it was exactly wat I was looking for, so please don't delete it because it could help somebody else. I voted you up and I think your question is the one that I was looking for.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I think you should keep it. I actually upvoted your answer. It explains to the OP why this behavior is happening (which is the OP asked).

Comment: @PraveenKumar, your question is correct and it helped me to have another problem that I could have in stackoverflow's snippets. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are using `forms`. The Stack Snippets will **not submit** forms. When you submit the form, you will see this in the console, the **browser console**:

> Blocked form submission to '' because the form's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-forms' permission is not set.

This is a sandboxed security feature implemented in Stack Snippets to avoid submission of user credentials and data from Stack Snippets to personal websites.

Try submitting the form here, and it will throw an error:

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

In the Chrome Console:

[image: console]

In the source of Stack Overflow page:

```
<iframe name="35ff969b-5580-7f20-bd3f-8c9fa41b341a" sandbox="allow-modals allow-scripts" class="snippet-box-edit" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```